# How to count the number of letters that exist without repeated

Tags: java, repeater

I want a way to count the letters in an string for example:

My string : "Hello my friends "

The characters in the string : {H,e,l,o, ,m,y,f,r,i,n,d,s}

These letters exist without repeating them (with a blank space)
So the result I want is: 13

The goal of all of this is, I want to convert a string to a table of character without repeating the letters

EX: MY String = "Hello"

The table I want to get {H,e,l,o}

My attempt

```
 public static int numberRep(String txt) {
    int count = 0;
        boolean v = false;
        for (int i = 0; i != txt.length(); i++) {
            char c = txt.charAt(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j != txt.length(); j++) {
                if (txt.charAt(j) == c) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == txt.length()-1){
                v = true;
            }
        }
        if(v){
            return 1 ;
        }
        else{
        return count;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try something, show us some code, and let us know where you get stuck. Hint: You could use a `HashSet<Character>` to store your unique characters, then the number of letters would be size of the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string into characters and store them into a `Set`. A `Set` keeps only unique elements. The elements of the `Set` will be the required characters and the size of the `Set` will give you the count of these characters.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "Hello my friends ";
        Set<String> set = Arrays.stream(myString.split("")).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
        System.out.println("Unique characters including space: " + set);
        System.out.println("No. of unique characters including space: " + set.size());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Unique characters including space: [H, e, l, o,  , m, y, f, r, i, n, d, s]
No. of unique characters including space: 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this could be one of the approach to do so:

```java
String str = "Hello my friends "
String noRepeatStr = "";

for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(noRepeatStr.indexOf(str[i]) == -1) // check if a char already exist, if not exist then return -1
        noRepeatStr = noRepeatStr+str[i];      // add new char
}

System.out.println("Letters: " + noRepeatStr.toCharArray())
System.out.println("No of letters: " + noRepeatStr.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

1. Create an empty list `a`
2. for character in list:
3. If the character is not your list `a`: add it to your list

This way you won't get any duplicate characters.

You can also use a set like recommended in Arvind's answer, but I think it is better for you to write a function as a task.
Set is the cleaner way to do it once you grasped the concepts of Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String test = "Hello my friends";

        final int size = IntStream.range(0, test.length())
                .mapToObj(test::charAt)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()).size();

        System.out.println(size);
    }
```

What I've done here is iterated over all of the characters in the input string, mapped them to a `char` object and then collected them into a `Set` - instead of keeping the raw `Set` I've used `.size()` in order to get the output that you were expecting.